# SUM a column count from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have this simple unioned query in SQL Server 2014 where I am getting counts of rows from each table, and then trying to add a TOTAL row at the bottom that will SUM the counts from both tables. I believe the problem is the LEFT OUTER JOIN on the last union seems to be only summing the totals from the first table

```
SELECT A.TEST_CODE, B.DIVISION, COUNT(*) 
FROM ALL_USERS B, SIGMA_TEST A
WHERE   B.DOMID = A.DOMID 
GROUP BY  A.TEST_CODE,  B.DIVISION 

UNION 

SELECT E.TEST_CODE, F.DIVISION, COUNT(*) 
FROM BETA_TEST E, ALL_USERS F
WHERE   E.DOMID = F.DOMID 
GROUP BY  E.TEST_CODE,  F.DIVISION

UNION 

SELECT 'TOTAL', '', COUNT(*) 
FROM (SIGMA_TEST A LEFT OUTER JOIN  BETA_TEST E ON  A.DOMID 
= E.DOMID )
```

**Here is a sample of the results I am getting:**

[image]

I would expect the TOTAL row to display a result of **6** (2+1+3=6)

I would like to avoid using a Common Table Expression (CTE) if possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are counting users with matching DOMIDs in the first two statements, the final statement also needs to include the ALL_USERS table. The final statement should be:

```
SELECT 'TOTAL', '', COUNT(*) 
FROM ALL_USERS G LEFT OUTER JOIN
SIGMA_TEST H ON G.DOMID = H.DOMID
LEFT OUTER JOIN BETA_TEST I ON I.DOMID = G.DOMID
WHERE (H.TEST_CODE IS NOT NULL OR I.TEST_CODE IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: My total is off 1 less than it should be. When I run this sql. I believe it's because the same DOMID exists in both tables (SIGMA_TEST and BETA_TEST), however I still want them to EACH count. How can I achieve this? Let me know if you want me to provide additional sample data...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this with a single query. It seems your test tables have similar structures, so you can union them together and join to `ALL_USERS`, finally, you can use [`GROUPING SETS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the total

```
SELECT  ISNULL(T.TEST_CODE, 'TOTAL') AS TEST_CODE, 
        ISNULL(U.DIVISION, '') AS DIVISION,
        COUNT(*)
FROM    ALL_USERS AS U
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  DOMID, TEST_CODE, 'SIGNMA' AS SOURCETABLE
            FROM    SIGMA_TEST
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  DOMID, TEST_CODE, 'BETA' AS SOURCETABLE
            FROM    BETA_TEST
        ) AS T
            ON T.DOMID = U.DOMID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((T.TEST_CODE, U.DIVISION, T.SOURCETABLE), ());
```

As an aside, [the implicit join syntax you are using was replaced over a quarter of a century ago in ANSI 92](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). It is not wrong, but there seems to be little reason to continue to use it, especially when you are mixing and matching with explicit outer joins and implicit inner joins. Anyone else that might read your SQL will certainly appreciate consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider doing a `UNION ALL` first *then* `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TEST_CODE, 'TOTAL'),  
       DIVISION, 
       COUNT(*)
FROM (
   SELECT A.TEST_CODE, B.DIVISION
   FROM ALL_USERS B
   INNER JOIN SIGMA_TEST A ON B.DOMID = A.DOMID

   UNION ALL

   SELECT E.TEST_CODE, F.DIVISION
   FROM BETA_TEST E
   INNER JOIN ALL_USERS F ON E.DOMID = F.DOMID ) AS T
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((TEST_CODE, DIVISION ), ())
```

Using `GROUPING SETS` you can easily get the total, so there is no need to add a third subquery.

**Note:** I assume you want *just one* count per `(TEST_CODE, DIVISION)`. Otherwise you have to also group on the source table as well, as in @Gareth's answer.